# Get selected value from drop down inside GridView on Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

So I have some GridView. When you edit a row, a particular column changes from a label to a DropDownList. The content of this drop down is populated via some SQL data source.
The user may make a selection choice and click "Update".

How can I actually get at the SelectedValue property of the drop down?

I thought this would work:

```
    <asp:GridView ... >
        <Columns>
            ...
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ServiceCategoriesGvDropDown" AutoPostBack="True" .../>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ... />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            ...
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And then wire it up with a ControlParameter in my SqlDataSource:

```
    <UpdateParameters>
        ...
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ServiceCategoriesGvDropDown" PropertyName="SelectedValue" ... />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

However, I get the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find control 'ServiceCategoriesGvDropDown' in ControlParameter 'ServiceCategoriesID'.

So clearly my drop down doesn't get found. Perhaps it's been destroyed by this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in the updating event of the grid.

```
 protected void YourGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
  DropDownList ddl= (DropDownList )YourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlId");
  string selectedvalue=ddl.selectedvalue;
  //Your update code goes here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need to do is:

1. Attach a `SelectedIndexChange` event to the `DropDownlist` on your `Gridview`
2. Grab the `SelectedValue` on that event.
3. Grab a reference to your DataSource's `UpdateParameters` and populate the respective parameter programmatically with the `SelectedValue`.
4. Call your DataSource's `Update` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:

assuming the ID of the gridview is gridview1

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gridview1$ServiceCategoriesGvDropDown" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
```